# implementing a cast operator in a generic abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, operator-keyword

I'm trying to be lazy and implement the cast operators in the abstract base class rather than in each of the derived concrete classes.  I've managed to cast one way, but I'm unable to cast the other.  I think it might not be possible, but wanted to pick the collective SO mind before giving up:

```
public interface IValueType<T>
{
    T Value{ get; set; }
}

public abstract class ValueType<T> : IValueType<T> {
    public abstract T Value { get; set; }
    public static explicit operator T(ValueType<T> vt) {
        if(vt == null)
            return default(T);
        return vt.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator ValueType<T>(T val) {
        ValueType<T> vt = new ValueType<T>(); //<--- obviously this won't work as its abstract
        vt.Value = val;
        return vt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Part of me thinks you could do this with reflection, but most of me says it makes more sense to do it in the derived classes, because it's the individual derived class's job to know how to go from T to it, not the job of the abstract class.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you can do it even with reflection, since they're static methods, and what I was thinking required instance methods.

Comment: @Matt Ellen I agree it's better to do it in the concrete classes but I'd rather write the method once rather than copy it into the dozens of derived classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to introduce another generic parameter to identify the concrete type.

something like..

```
public interface IValueType<T> 
{    
    T Value{ get; set; } 
} 

public abstract class ValueType<T,K> : 
    IValueType<T> where K : ValueType<T,K>,new()
{     
    public abstract T Value { get; set; }     
    public static explicit operator T(ValueType<T,K> vt) 
    {         
        if(vt == null)            
            return default(T);         
        return vt.Value;     
    }      

    public static implicit operator ValueType<T,K>(T val) 
    {         
        K k = new K();
        k.Value = val;
        return k;    
    } 
}
```

Create your concrete class

```
public class Test : ValueType<int,Test>
{
    public override int Value {get;set;}
}
```

Then

```
var t = new Test();
t.Value = 99;
int i = (int)t;
Test t2 = (Test)6;

Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.WriteLine(t2);
```

Comment: I see that you still have to explicitly cast an `int` to `Test`: `Test t2 = (Test)6;`. I guess that's because we can't implement `public static implicit operator K(T val){...}` without incurring a compile-time error (CS0556).

Comment: I thought of a solution of chaining the implicit operators but got stuck there, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001854/chaining-implicit-operators-in-generic-c-classes