# How do lambda expressions work with implicit casting?

Tags: c#, lambda, implicit-conversion

I'm a bit confused on how C# handles lambda expression with regard to implicit casting.

My goal is similar to the following minimal example:

```
A<int>.DoSomething(x => x == 42);

public static class A<T>
{
    public static void DoSomething(PredicateAdapter<T> _) { }
}

public class PredicateAdapter<T>
{
    public static implicit operator PredicateAdapter<T>(Predicate<T> _) => new();
}
```

So I'd like to create a wrapper for predicates, that allows me to do fancy stuff (which is not listed here in this example for the sake of brevity.) However, the code above does not compile, because "Error CS1660 : Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'PredicateAdapter' because it is not a delegate type".

In contrast, here is an example where implicit casting works:

```
A<int>.DoSomething(x => x == 42);

public static class A<T>
{
    public static void DoSomething(Predicate<T> _) { }
}
```

The compiler is able to infer that the lambda expression `x => x == 42` can be implicitly cast to `Predicate<int>` and passes this happily along to `A<int>.DoSomething(Predicate<int>)`.

Also, explicitly casting the lambda to `Predicate<int>` means my custom implicit casting is applied and works:

```
A<int>.DoSomething((Predicate<int>)(x => x == 42));

public static class A<T>
{
    public static void DoSomething(PredicateAdapter<T> _) { }
}

public class PredicateAdapter<T>
{
    public static implicit operator PredicateAdapter<T>(Predicate<T> _) => new();
}
```

So, my question is: Why do I need to cast the lambda explicitly (and write much less readable code), when C# is apparently able to do this cast implicitly? And: Is it somehow possible to modify the classes `A` and `PredicateAdapter` so that I can use a simple lambda expression (without any explicit casting) and still use the `PredicateAdapter`?

Comment: What "fancy stuff" are you doing?

Comment: Sadly, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6002558/2557128) for why it didn't work in 2011 and still doesn't work. Basically an implicit conversion chain can only include one user-defined conversion and two standard implicit conversions, and lambda to delegate type is not a standard implicit conversion.

Comment: @Sweeper: Take a look at the `Arg` class in this commit: [Github commit](https://github.com/Phoenox/fluentassertions-callbacks/commit/5d9e9e9319d86b961629b4eba42c57fac94bb268)
For predicates, I have to put a `Arg<T>.Is(...)` around every lambda, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding it is "because the specification says so". As [12.19 Anonymous function expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12191-general) section states:

> An anonymous function does not have a value or type in and of itself, but is convertible to a compatible delegate or expression-tree type.

So when you are using anonymous function (lambda expression) compiler should decide what type it should be (since you are not specifying type explicitly). Since you have a parameter which is not a delegate type (like `Predicate<T>`) or expression tree type (i.e. `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>`) the compiler produces error.

Also from [10.7 Anonymous function conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#107-anonymous-function-conversions):

> An `anonymous_method_expression` or `lambda_expression` is classified as an anonymous function (§12.19). The expression does not have a type, but can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type. Some lambda expressions may also be implicitly converted to a compatible expression tree type.

Also [Lambda improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements#natural-function-type) in C# 10 can be an interesting read.

Comment: I think the discussion of implicit conversion is just as important as to why it doesn't happen.

Comment: @NetMage If I understand you correctly - it could be but (as far as I understand) it is "next step", so compiler "stops" even before the implicit conversion becomes a factor.

Comment: Not exactly. Implicit conversions are allowed for a chain of (standard implicit conversion) -> (user defined conversion) -> (standard implicit conversion) but anonymous function (lambda) expressions have no (usable) type, and their only implicit conversion is to a delegate type, and that conversion is not part of the list of standard implicit conversions, so it is never considered. I personally think lambda expression to delegate type should be added to the list of standard conversions, especially given the lambda expression type improvements in C# 10 & 12.